# FusedLocationProviderApi not working

Tags: java, android

```
try {
    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
} catch (SecurityException exception) {
```

At the `(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, this);` part, it gives me a red line saying:

> Cannot resolve method 'requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest, com...mapsActivity)'

Anyone has experience with this and how to fix it?
Or am I using the code all wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Jamie

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter is supposed to be a `LocationListener`. If you want to use the activity as the callback receiver, it has to implement the `LocationListener` interface and its method:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
    // Do something with the location here...
}
```

Reference: [requestLocationUpdates(GoogleApiClient, LocationRequest, LocationListener)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener))

Comment: Thank you, it partially helped. However, it gives me the 'Expression expected' error with the LocationListener. Any idea what to input there?